# Should the stage-magic tag include tricks not performed for audiences?

Tags: discussion, tags

[Can you predict a number that is "randomly" chosen by a person better than chance?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/36652/can-you-predict-a-number-that-is-randomly-chosen-by-a-person-better-than-chanc?noredirect=1#comment141687_36652)

### Should this question have the stage magic tag?

Here are some opinions by  @Sklivvz

"why not? it's conceivably a stage-magic trick, the cartoon presents is as a trick, and it's not dissimilar from cold reading tricks"

" the tag excerpt for stage-magic says 'staged tricks or illusions of seemingly impossible or supernatural feats using natural means', which seem to be a perfect description. 'Magic' is a bad tag in general as it has overloaded meanings, and presumes a supernatural cause."

There are the opinions that I have about the subject:

" I would not pay to see a guy guess my random number... The trick is not worthy of a stage audience. Magic might be an appropriate tag, but not stage magic."

"stage-magic implies that there is some sort of performance. This is a simple trick not a performance."

#### All of the questions with the "Stage-magic" tag involve live performance magic performed for entertainment.

I don't see how my question relates to the stage magic tag. Seeing as it is not related to magic performance.

Comment: I personally don't think we should be continuing comment threads in meta...

Comment: The discussion should not be between you and I. Since the discussion is about the definition of a tag, it should include anyone who wants to contribute.

Comment: We are talking about a *single case* right now. If you want to have an appropriate meta conversation, look how the tag is used and see if there are any discrepancies, or points worth making first.

Comment: Example of the claim in question being performed as stage magic: http://www.cs4fn.org/mathemagic/streetmagic.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was about to explain why we specify "stage" in "stage-magic", when I realised the [stage-magic](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stage-magic)'s tag description already does it:

> Referred to as stage or street magic to distinguish it from paranormal or ritual magic. It is one of the oldest performing arts in the world in which audiences are entertained by staged tricks or illusions of seemingly impossible or supernatural feats using natural means.

The "stage" part isn't really about whether it appears on a real, live, area designated for performing where the audience can see you stage. It is about it being a deliberate illusion performed with natural means.

(Some people use "magic" versus "magick" to make a similar disambiguation.)